# Making the dots in a TOC go all the way up to a number (using titletoc)

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titletoc

I’m using the `titletoc` package to create a TOC. How can I make sure that my dotted lines always touch the number? More precisely, I want the dotted lines to look as in the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using `\contentsmargin` and `\dottedcontents`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{0pt}
\renewcommand\contentspage{\thecontentspage}

\dottedcontents{section}[2.3em]{}{2.3em}{5pt}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[5.5em]{}{3.2em}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{test test test test test test}
\subsection{test}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{12}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}

\end{document}
```

And the obtained ToC:

[image]

Personally, I don't like much this layout, and would prefer some uniform white space between the rightmost dot and the page numbers.